# Is there way to define compare (`==`) function automatically for `struct` in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift-structs

Let's assume we have a pretty big `struct` in Swift:

```
struct SuperStruct {
    var field1: Int = 0
    var field2: String = ""
    // lots of lines...
    var field512: Float = 0.0
}
```

.. and then we need to implement `Equatable` protocol:

```
extension SuperStruct: Equatable {
}

func ==(lhs: SuperStruct, rhs: SuperStruct) -> Bool {
    return
        lhs.field1 == rhs.field1 &&
        lhs.field2 == rhs.field2 &&
        // lots of lines...
        lhs.field512 == rhs.field512
}
```

... and we need to write lots of lines of stupid code.
Is there a way "to ask" compiler "to do" it for us?

Comment: You should take a look at protocol extensions. WWDC 2015 Session 408. http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/408509vyudbqvts/408/408_hd_protocoloriented_programming_in_swift.mp4?dl=1

Comment: How hard do you thing it will be to write a small helper that will parse a piece of your code and generate the required method ? Add versions for beans on top of that to track the code that might need to be updated and you are good.

Comment: Leo Dabus, Thanks! I am aware of how protocol extension works, but I have no idea how can I use it with my issue.

Comment: A-Live, Yes, i can do something like this but I am looking for compiler native feature. I just believe it should exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Swift 4.1, Equatable/Hashable types now synthesize conformance to Equatable/Hashable if all of the types' members are Equatable/Hashable

#### SE-0185

#### Synthesizing Equatable and Hashable conformance

> Developers have to write large amounts of boilerplate code to support equatability and hashability of complex types. This proposal offers a way for the compiler to automatically synthesize conformance to Equatable and Hashable to reduce this boilerplate, in a subset of scenarios where generating the correct implementation is known to be possible.

https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0185-synthesize-equatable-hashable.md

Answer (score 5):

The following answer shows one *possible* solution; possibly not a recommended one (however possibly of interest for future readers of this question).

---

If you have a large number of properties which all belong to a somewhat limited of number different *types*, you could use a `Mirror` of your structure instances and iterate over over the structures' properties; for each attempting conversion to the different types *that you know* your properties to be.

I've edited the previous answer (to something I believe is quite much neater), after watching the following WWDC 2015 session (thanks Leo Dabus!):

- [WWDC 2015 session 408](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/408509vyudbqvts/408/408_hd_protocoloriented_programming_in_swift.mp4?dl=1). Recommended.

I'll leave the initial answer in the bottom of this answer as well, as it shows an alternative, less protocol-oriented approach, to make use of this `Mirror` solution.

***`Mirror` & protocol-oriented solution:***

```
/* Let a heterogeneous protocol act as "pseudo-generic" type
   for the different (property) types in 'SuperStruct'         */
protocol MyGenericType {
    func isEqualTo(other: MyGenericType) -> Bool
}
extension MyGenericType where Self : Equatable {
    func isEqualTo(other: MyGenericType) -> Bool {
        if let o = other as? Self { return self == o }
        return false
    }
}

/* Extend types that appear in 'SuperStruct' to MyGenericType  */
extension Int : MyGenericType {}
extension String : MyGenericType {}
extension Float : MyGenericType {}
    // ...

/* Finally, 'SuperStruct' conformance to Equatable */
func ==(lhs: SuperStruct, rhs: SuperStruct) -> Bool {

    let mLhs = Mirror(reflecting: lhs).children.filter { $0.label != nil }
    let mRhs = Mirror(reflecting: rhs).children.filter { $0.label != nil }

    for i in 0..<mLhs.count {
        guard let valLhs = mLhs[i].value as? MyGenericType, valRhs = mRhs[i].value as? MyGenericType else {
            print("Invalid: Properties 'lhs.\(mLhs[i].label!)' and/or 'rhs.\(mRhs[i].label!)' are not of 'MyGenericType' types.")
            return false
        }
        if !valLhs.isEqualTo(valRhs) {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Example usage:

```
/* Example */
var a = SuperStruct()
var b = SuperStruct()
a == b // true
a.field1 = 2
a == b // false
b.field1 = 2
b.field2 = "Foo"
a.field2 = "Foo"
a == b // true
```

---

***Previous `Mirror` solution:***

```
/* 'SuperStruct' conformance to Equatable */
func ==(lhs: SuperStruct, rhs: SuperStruct) -> Bool {

    let mLhs = Mirror(reflecting: lhs).children.filter { $0.label != nil }
    let mRhs = Mirror(reflecting: rhs).children.filter { $0.label != nil }

    for i in 0..<mLhs.count {
        switch mLhs[i].value {
        case let valLhs as Int:
            guard let valRhs = mRhs[i].value as? Int where valRhs == valLhs else {
                return false
            }
        case let valLhs as String:
            guard let valRhs = mRhs[i].value as? String where valRhs == valLhs else {
                return false
            }
        case let valLhs as Float:
            guard let valRhs = mRhs[i].value as? Float where valRhs == valLhs else {
                return false
            }
            /* ... extend with one case for each type
            that appear in 'SuperStruct'  */
        case _ : return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Example usage:

```
/* Example */
var a = SuperStruct()
var b = SuperStruct()
a == b // true
a.field1 = 2
a == b // false
b.field1 = 2
b.field2 = "Foo"
a.field2 = "Foo"
a == b // true
```

Comment: Wow, nice hack. +1. Scary, and probably proof that one probably *shouldn't* try to avoid writing `Equatable` conformance more directly.

Comment: That's awesome! Probably it is not production solution (it should be slow, I believe) but I definitely can use it in development while a set of properties in SuperStruct unstable.

Comment: How would you make Array conform to MyGenericType?

Answer (score 2):

You could make the struct Codable and compare the JSON encoded Data.  Not efficient, but could be useful for some applications (e.g. unit tests).

```
struct SuperStruct: Encodable {
    var field1: Int = 0 
    // ....
    var field512: Float = 0.0
}

let s1 = SuperStruct()
let s2 = SuperStruct()

let encoder = JSONEncoder()
let data1 = try! encoder.encode(s1)
let data2 = try! encoder.encode(s2)
let result = (data1 == data2)
```

If you like this you could tidy it up into a protocol extension of `Encodable`.

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't. At least not in any way that's not excessively complicated and based on use (abuse?) of runtime introspection. See [dfri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35024643/957768) for something that technically works, but that is *way* more complicated than just writing an `==` implementation that directly compares all fields.

As for your opinions on what "should" be available in Swift, you're more likely to see some effect if you share them [with Apple](http://bugreport.apple.com) or with the [Swift open source community](http://swift.org).